# Performance drops down x64 with OpenMP

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, 64-bit, openmp

I noticed a very strange behavior while running my code in x64 "mode" with VS 2008, in Release mode.

I seek for the performance improvement, thus I turned my project to x64 platform (my original project is written as a console application Win32).

I indeed gained some improvement, but also I found a very strange behavior during the run. I use OpenMP pragmas to parallelize loops ("for"). So when I run my program (Win32) on quad core i5 processor, I see 100% of CPU load and 4 threads. It's OK.

But when I switch to x64 mode (in Projet Properties->Configuration Manager->...) the 100% load **Drops Down** (after 3-5 minutes) to 75%, 50%, or even 25%. But still, there are 4 (!) threads run. (According to Resource Monitor).

How it is possible to have only 25% of the total CPU performance with all 4 treads? Each thread suppose to run on its individual core.

P.S. OS Windows 7 x64 and VS 2008.

Thanks in advance! Any suggestions are much appreciated!

A.K.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible, since there is no short and self contained part. Roughly speaking, there are two nested "for" loops which fill 2D matrix with cumbersome integral expression at each matrix cell.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I think I do know the answer for my question: only 25% of CPU load while all 4 treads are active, means that 3 of 4 cores finished their job and wait for the last core to finish his job. Probably this core is stuck with computations (there is an integral calculations and if integral does not converge, it tries to reduce stepsize and continue calculations).

I do not know for sure, it is my guess.